# Notification and notification click event with FCM in PWA

Tags: javascript, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, progressive-web-apps, service-worker

I received 2 notifications in background case and can not handle click in foreground case

I am implementing push notification function on PWA using FCM. But I am getting issues

1. In background case. On firebase-messaging-sw.js file. I implemented

```
self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {}
```

I received 2 notifications. But this event only runs when I click notification is clicked by onBackgroundMessage

```
messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  const { title, body, icon, tag } = payload.notification;
  self.registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: body
    tag: tag 
    icon: icon
    data: { url: payload.data.link },
  });
});
```

How to disable default background notification. I want to only show notification 1 time handled by onBackgroundMessage

2. On foreground case. I call registration.showNotification() to show notification in onMessage event to display notification. How to handle the click event in this case? notificationclick in firebase-messaging-sw.js seem is not work.

This is my sw file:

```
importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-app-compat.js'
);
importScripts(
  'https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.7.0/firebase-messaging-compat.js'
);

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
const messaging = firebase.messaging();

messaging.onBackgroundMessage((payload) => {
  const { title, body, icon, tag } = payload.notification;
  self.registration.showNotification(title, {
    body: body,
    tag: tag,
    icon: icon,
    data: { url: payload.data.link },
  });
});

self.addEventListener('push', function (event) {
  console.log('Received a push message', event);
});

self.addEventListener('notificationclick', function (event) {
  console.log('On notification click: ', event);
  let data = event.notification.data;
  event.notification.close();
  self.clients.openWindow(data.url);
});
```